# Why does Perl Net::Google::Search fail for me?

Tags: perl

I am having the following trouble getting `Net::Google::Search` to work. I have obtained an API key from google so I assume my attempted usage is copacetic.

```
use strict;
use Net::Google::Search;

my %args = (

    key => 'MyGoogleAPIKey',
    starts_at => 0,
    max_results => 5,

    );

my $search = Net::Google::Search->new(\%args);
```

Executing this code I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /home/richard/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Google/Service.pm line 80.
Service description 'file:' can't be loaded: 404 File `' does not exist
```

Comment: Have you tried ```new(%args)``` instead of ```new(\%args)```? This would more be what I would expects as an interface in perl. I think, the way it should be used might be like ```Net::Google::Search->new(key => 'MyGoogleAPIKey', max_results => 5)```.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately `my $search = Net::Google::Search->new(key => 'MyGoogleAPIKey', max_results => 5);` Gives me the exact same result.

Comment: Re "Related?" There's a good chance that switching to Google::Search won't help. Since at least 2012, the module's docs say it uses a deprecated API.  But, it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=53447), the API used by Net::Google::Search has been dead since 2009, and it hasn't even been possible to install the module since 2005.

I don't know if that's the issue you are facing, but it doesn't matter. You're not going to get anywhere with that module.

Comment: Any ideas what I can try instead?

Comment: Start by finding out what APIs are available, if any